# Are these two definitions of one-way function equivalent?

Tags: probability, computational-complexity, cryptography

Here comes two definition of one-way function, the first one comes from wikipedia while the second one is by myself.

I'm curious about whether they are equivalent and have been considering for a long time.

For short, I won't write "easy to compute" part, and focus on "hard to invert".

> **Deinition 1**.
> A function $f:\{0,1\}^*\rightarrow\{0,1\}^*$ is hard to invert if:
>
> For all probabilistic polynomial time algorithm $A$, and for all polynomial $p(n)$, it holds
>
> $$
> \exists N\in\mathbb{N}.\;\text{s.t. }\forall n\geq N.\;\mathop{\text{Prob}}_{x\sim U_n}[f(A(f(x)))=f(x)]\leq\frac{1}{p(n)} 
> $$
> where $U_n$ is the uniform distribution over $\{0,1\}^n$.

> **Definition 2**.
> A function $f:\{0,1\}^*\rightarrow\{0,1\}^*$ is hard to invert if:
>
> For all probabilistic polynomial time algorithm $A$, and for all polynomial $p(n)$, it holds
> $$
> \exists N\in\mathbb{N}.\;\text{s.t. }\forall n\geq N.\;\mathop{\text{Prob}}_{y\sim U_S}[f(A(y))=y]\leq\frac{1}{p(n)}
> $$
> where $U_S$ is the uniform distribution over $S=\{f(x)\mid |x|=n\}$.

Is this two definitions equivalent?
Intuitively I think they are not, but if possible please show me an example $f$.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think yours is stronger and better...